# Is this a driver issue, and if so, is there a way to rollback to a previous version?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

Problem: I can run Ubuntu (Latest Version) through Recovery, but I can't run it 'normally'.

Most people online seem to say that this situation is typically an issue with your Video Card Drivers--

Counter Argument: On the other hand however, when I try to run Ubuntu's Installer and say 'Try Ubuntu' it runs perfectly. 4K resolution, everything seems smooth-- so why would it be any different for my official install?

The first step towards getting the drivers is figuring out which card I have. So I put in the command `lspci | grep VGA` and it returned:

```
 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
```

So I either have 7950, 8950 or R9 280? Wasn't sure which one, so I went to check a few.

R9 280: on the website https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux it shows

Radeon™ R7 300, R9 295X2, R9 280X, R9 280, R9 270X, R9 270, R7 265,HD 8700 - HD 8900, and HD 7900 Series

```
RHEL ​​(32-bit | ​64-bit)
Ubuntu ​15.04 ​​(32-bit | ​64-bit)
​Ubuntu 14.04.2​​​ ​​(32-bit | ​64-bit)
​Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS​​ ​​(32-bit | ​64-bit)
Linux​ ​​(32-bit | ​64-bit)
```

Which seems to imply that the R9 280 and the 7950 are only compatible on Ubuntu 15.04.

However, on this website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver it shows

TAHITI
Radeon HD 7900 series
Radeon R9 280/280X

Then has a box for 12.04 | 14.04 | and 16.04 with either a Check or an 'X'

For TAHITI, 12.04 has an 'X', 14.04 has a Check with an ! and 16.04 has a Check.

Doesn't this seem to imply I should be good on 16.04? Yet the drivers only go to 15.04? Is there any way to make them work on 18.04? If not, can I scale back to 16.04 without re-installing everything, and if so, am I losing very much?

Sorry for the long question, but i'm a complete beginner to Linux/Ubuntu and would really like to use this operating system.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: the website of AMD is out-of-date about Linux driver; 15.04 is EOL from more than 2 years, but don't be afraid, some (or even) AMD graphical card support Ubuntu, their builtin driver is in some case compatible with Ubuntu, or just need to be adjust (like in your case), but I can't say you how, haven't got any problem with a Radeon R7 M260 (nothing needed to be installed to see it works)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of how I should proceed from here?